# Permitir texto en ISBN con Prestashop

Tags: php, javascript, prestashop

Como digo en el titulo necesito introducir letras en el campo ISBN en prestashop.

Por defecto solo se pueden números y hasta 32 caracteres y necesito poder escribir texto y poner mínimo 120 caracteres.

**He probado a cambiar la siguiente linea en classes/Validate.php (sin éxito):**

**Original**:

```
return !$isbn || preg_match('/^[0-9-]{0,32}$/', $isbn);
```

**Modificado:**

```
return !$isbn || preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z 0-9-\(\)-]{0,120}$/', $isbn);
```

**También en el archivo classes/Product.php he cambiado (sin éxito):**

**Original:**

```
'isbn' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isIsbn', 'size' => 32)
```

**Modificado:**

```
'isbn' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isIsbn', 'size' => 120)
```

**Y en la base de datos en la tabla ps_product he aumentado el valor y tampoco funciona:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He borrado caché por si alguien lo pregunta.

Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En clases/Validate.php prueba directamente con esto:

```
 public static function isIsbn($isbn)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Posteriormente lo vas afinando para validar, pero si pones eso no realiza comprobación y por tanto debería funcionarte.